# Cannot change global shortcuts on Ubuntu 20.04 with KDE: “Failed to contact the KDE global shortcuts daemon”

Tags: kde, shortcuts

I would like to change the ALT-CTRL-L shortcut in Ubuntu 20.04. Custom shortcuts module or Standard shortcuts module is working. But I'm trying to open Global shortcuts module on Ubuntu 20.04 with KDE, but after open Settings => Global shortcuts window will freeze and after short time will display the following message: "Failed to contact the KDE global shortcuts daemon".

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GluI6.png)

Thanks a lot for each answer.

Comment: Have you asked the same question in 2 different places?

Comment: @David yes, because first time I asked on StackOverflow and after recommendation to askubuntu, I opened the question also here. Can you help me with my question? I need to change the ALT+CTRL+L, because same shortcut I need to use in Webstorm. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorry not an expert on changing keys configurations. Just noticed that the question was in 2 sites which is generally frowned on..